# How to create identical objects with a button in Xcode, Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, class, button

Let's say I want to create a list of buttons. I have a button B, that, when clicked, creates a list of buttons A in this way.

[image]

Then, when every button A is clicked, it deletes itself.

How can I do this? 
Thank you

Comment: Tons of ways to do this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Nothing yet, what do you suggest?

Comment: A simple google search, to _create UIButton programmatically_ and _delete UIButton programatically_ will do. Next time though, please try to use every possible resource before posting a question on SO.

Comment: Yes but then how can I link every new button to their method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you will need a few things:

- An `IBOutlet` to the `NSView` that is automatically in your `NSWindow`. I called mine `mainView`. (Note: I did this with Cocoa on a Mac, hence the `NSWindow`, although I imagine this process would be very similar on iOS/Cocoa Touch)
- Two images, one of the A button and one of the B button, called "A" and "B".

If the A button is going to be reproduced as many times as we wish, we will need an A button class. The A button class has an initializer that programmatically turns it into an "Image Button", eg. a button that has an image on its face instead of text. Also, the `AButton` class implements `touchesBegan:`, a function that listens for clicks on the button. When a click is performed, the button calls that function. The button then removes itself from whatever view it is in.

```
class AButton: NSButton {
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)

        self.bezelStyle = .regularSquare
        self.setButtonType(.momentaryPushIn)
        self.isBordered = false
        self.image = NSImage(named: "A") // puts image on the face of the button
    }

    override func touchesBegan(with event: NSEvent) { // "when button is clicked..."
        self.removeFromSuperview() // remove from view
    }
}
```

Next, we need a function to be performed when the B button is clicked. Use Interface Builder (IB) to drag an "Image Button" onto the main window. In the toolbar, select the image of this button to be "B". Then, drag an IBAction from the B button to your AppDelegate (or controller file/class, whatever it may be). This function runs a loop that creates many AButton instances, positions them correctly, and then adds them to the `NSView` using `addSubview()`. Whenever one of them is pressed, it will remove itself from the view.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainView: NSView! // outlet to NSView in main window

@IBAction func bButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        for i in 0...3 {
            let x = 50 + i*110
            let y = 50

            let theButton = AButton(frame: NSMakeRect(CGFloat(x), CGFloat(y), 100, 100))
            mainView.addSubview(theButton) // adds newly created AButton to the view
        }
}
```

Comment: But then how can I link the IBAction i'll create to remove the A Buttons when they're clicked to every A Buttons?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways..

**iOS**

For the "button A", i will prefer UICollectionViewCell.

**Advantages**

1. UICollectionView has UIScrollView and dynamically manage its contentSize automatically.
2. UICollectionViewCell will be reused. so memory issue and performance issue will not be there.